# does $4097$ divide $2^{4097}-2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

does $4097$ devide $2^{4097}-2$ ?
It was long since I did number theory.

$4097 = 17\times241$.

I know have that both 17 and 241 does not divide $2^{4097}-2$ (with fermats little theorem)

Is there a easier way to see this?

Comment: If 17 doesn't divide it, how could 4097?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that if you know that $17$ (or $241$) does not divide $2^{4097}- 2$, it cannot be the case that $4097 = 17\cdot 241$ divides it.

$$pq\mid a \implies (p\mid a\;\text{ and }\;q \mid a)$$

Stated in its contrapositive form, $$(p \not \mid a\;\text{ or }\;q\not\mid a) \implies pq\not\mid a$$

Answer (score 2):

4097 is only 1 more than 4096 which is $2^{12}$ and 4096 $\equiv$ -1 mod 4097. That provides an easy way to do the modular arithmetic without even factoring 4097.

$2^{4097}$ = $2^{5}$* $(2^{12})^{341}$.

$(2^{12})^{341}$ $\equiv$ $-1^{341}$ $\equiv$ -1 mod 4097

So $2^{4097}$ $\equiv$ $2^{5}$*-1 $\equiv$ -32 mod 4097

rather than 2 which is what you were originally asked to disprove.